# Azure ARM - Inline Conditional Statement

Tags: json, azure, templates

I am wondering if it is possible to perform an inline conditional statement in my Azure ARM Template.  In short, I want to assign a Public IP Address to a NIC if a given parameter is set to "Yes"

```
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
          "name": "my-network-interface",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
              {
                "name": "ipconfig1",
                "properties": {
                  "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                  "subnet": {
                    "id": "my-subnet-name"
                  },
                  "privateIpAddress": "10.0.0.5",
                  IF ASSIGN PUBLIC IP THEN,
                       "publicIpAddress": "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'my-public-ip)]"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd have to use `union()` and `if()` functions to achieve that. create these variables:

```
"external": {
    "publicIPAddress": {
        "id": "my_ip_id"
    }
},
"internal": {
    "privateIPAddress": "10.0.0.5",
    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
    "subnet": {
        "id": "my_subnet_id"
    }
},
```

and then do something like this:

```
"ipConfigurations": [
    {
        "name": "ipconfig1",
        "properties": "[if(equals(parameters('something'), 'yes'), union(variables('external'), variables('external')), variables('internal'))]"
    }
]
```

alternative (if you dont care about code duplication) you can create 2 different deployments with slightly different code, one would deploy condition 1 other would deploy condition 2. as a bonus this approach is easier to understand, but harder to maintain.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!